# How to display error message into a Json using ResponseStatusException on Spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have an issue displaying an error message at the moment that a bad request is triggered.

```
@DeleteMapping("/{projectId}/bugs/{bugId}")
public void deleteBug(@PathVariable (value = "projectId") Long projectId,
                      @PathVariable (value = "bugId") Long bugId){
    if (!projectService.existById(projectId) || !bugService.existById(bugId)) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "ProjectId " + projectId + " or BugId " + bugId + " not found");
    }
    bugService.deleteBug(bugId);
}
```

This is the JSON response when I trigger the Response:

```
{
"timestamp": "2020-05-29T15:40:41.302+00:00",
"status": 400,
"error": "Bad Request",
"message": "",
"path": "/projects/3/bugs/2"  }
```

As you can see the message is not appearing. If I change the HttpStatus in the code it actually works but for some reason, the message is not working.

I checked the constructor of the class and it actually allows only the status and the reason.

Am I missing something or is it a bug in the ResponseStatusException class?

Comment: Please check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61659000/restcontrolleradvice-is-not-working-i-am-using-spring-boot-2-2-6-version/61659679#61659679

Comment: Which spring-boot version do you use? You may use older versions such as `2.2.6.RELEASE`. I have the same problem with version `2.3.0.RELEASE`, which is the newest by the time of this comment. Everything is good with the previous ones.

Comment: @AchmadYogiPrakoso thank you a lot for your comment. I will give it a try because you are right, I'm using the newest spring boot version

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I also encountered this. It's not a bug, so downgrading is not the best resolution. The [Spring Boot 2.3.0 release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.3-Release-Notes#changes-to-the-default-error-pages-content) explain:

> #### Changes to the Default Error Page's Content
>
> The error message and any binding errors are no longer included in the
>   default error page by default. This reduces the risk of leaking
>   information to a client. `server.error.include-message` and
>   `server.error.include-binding-errors` can be used to control the
>   inclusion of the message and binding errors respectively. Supported
>   values are `always`, `on-param`, and `never`.

So for example, in your application configuration you can set these to show `message` but not `trace` output (YAML example):

```yaml
server:
  error:
    include-message: ALWAYS
    include-stacktrace: NEVER
```